# Multiple subdomains to same address

Tags: apache, subdomain, vhosts

I want to redirect multiple subdomain to same address. 
Let's say I want www.sitename.com and sitename.com to redirect same address.

Do I have to say;

```
<VirtualHost www.sitename.com:81>
    .
    .
    .
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost sitename.com:81>
    .
    .
    .
</VirtualHost>
```

or is there a simple solution.

Comment: what do you mean by `redirect`? You mean when you type in the browser you want it to redirect to another address or you want to show the same content with different subdomains?

Comment: I want to show the same content with different subdomains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, If you wish to use multiple addresses like subdomains to the same location you can do this.

```
<VirtualHost *:81>
     ServerName example.com
     ServerAlias www.example.com sub1.example.com sub2.example.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com
     #more stuff etc here if needed    
</VirtualHost>
```

It's part of name based virtual host.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html